# Get event name FROM CiviEvent in activity subject

Tags: civirules

When a certain event is created with CiviEvent, I have a Civirule creating a related activity. I need to grab the name of the event to use it as the subject of the activity. By default it would be empty or fixed.

Where would you start coding?

[image: CiviRule]

EDIT 1: we are adding a new 'Add Action' following [this guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-action/)

EDIT 2: I know the action is triggered when adding an event so their must be a way to get the variable of the event_id so I can use APIv3 and get the event_title.

I tested to echo variables in the subject field but it doesn't quite work.

I searched on APIv3 in order to have the event_title but I need the event id.

```
if (!empty($data['subject'])) {
  $return = '';
  $params = $this->getActionParameters();
  $defaultValues['subject'] = civicrm_api3('Event', 'getvalue', [
  'return' => 'title',
  'id' => $params['event_id']]);
$return .= ts("Subject: %1", [1 => $subject]);
return $return;
}
```

What should we improve?

Comment: do you mean 'event' as in a CiviEvent? just aware the term 'event' has multiple uses

Comment: yes the title of the event from CiviEVENT.

Comment: When you say echoing the variables doesn't work, not sure what you mean. If you want to see the whole params array use something like var_export($params, true). You can also output that to the civi log with CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message().

Comment: I'm working on uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicoop.civirules/CRM/CivirulesActions/Activity.php


 echo var_export($params, true) result in NULL maybe this explain why my echo didn't work but the file is still using variables


CRM_Core_Error::debug_log_message() don't log anything in my console.